# KeyError in creating attribute in Python for Sentinel 5p

Tags: python, sentinel-5p, keyerror

I was doing analysis of NO2 emission using Sentinel 5p following the training of RUS Copernicus ATM002. When I was creating an attribute function it works fine. But when I call it in a function it says KeyError. As I’m a beginner in Python; I cannot understand where the problem is. Here is my code and error msg.

```
attributes = {
    i.split('/')[-1]:{
        'time_coverage_start': xr.open_dataset(i).attrs['time_coverage_start']
    } for i in input_files_offl
}

#Print only first items in dictionary as example
dict(itertools.islice(attributes.items(),3))



def preprocess(ds):
        ds['time'] = pd.to_datetime(np.array([attributes[ds.attrs['source_product']]['time_coverage_start']])).values
        return ds

L3_march_20 = xr.open_mfdataset(filename_L3, combine='nested', concat_dim='time', preprocess=preprocess, chunks={'time':100})
L3_march_20
```

And I found this:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please always post errors as text (with code formatting) not as screenshots

Comment: thanks. as I'm new I don't know it very well.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/401368/edit) and post errors as text (with code formatting)

Comment: I think the problem is that you use a full pathname ("F:\...\file.nc4") as key in the `attributes` dictionary. In your preprocess function you get the key from `ds.attrs['source_product']` and that key seems to be only the filename ("file.nc4")